# How to do grep of string (which contains file directory path as value ) in a input file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have string value as `/tmp/Sne/test1.list` and I have a file called `all_tests.txt`

This all_tests.txt contains lines below:

```
/tmp/Sne/test1.list
/tmp/Sne/test2.list
/tmp/Sne/test3.list
/tmp/Sne/test4.list
```

How to use `grep` to search if string value `/tmp/Sne/test1.list` is present in the `all_tests.txt`.
If present then I need to `echo` a message that file is present.

I tried using:

```
if [ grep -Fxq "$p" $Input_file ]; then echo "This file list is already checked"
```

where `$p` is `/tmp/Sne/test1.list` and `$Input_file` is `all_tests.txt`

This is not working.

Kindly request for help.

Comment: The brackets don't make sense. `if` executes the _then_ part, if the program invoked returns exit code 0.

Comment: `This is not working` is the worst possible description of a problem, no more useful here than if you took your car to a mechanic for repair and all you would tell them is `This is not working`. Tell us in what way it's not working (no output, wrong output, error messages, etc.) so we can help you repair it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
if grep -Fxq "$p" "$Input_file"; then echo "This file list is already checked"; fi
```

You were mixing two commands: `[` (`man test`) and `grep`.

PS: surround your variables with double quotes (`$Input_file` => `"$Input_file"`) unless you are certain you must not.